Insecure Deserialization in C# (.NET) using NewtonsoftJson
I am working on a Web API that needs to call a 3rd party Web API to achieve some features. That 3rd party's API's design is sort of a "God API" such that it takes a generic object type to allow that single API to be used for MANY different features with MANY different settings (900+). I've setup a minimal example in the first commit of this repo
(the TestRequests.http file can be used in Rider IDE's HTTP client plugin or you can just copy it into something similar like postman)
Despite me setting TypeNameHandling.None, the security reviewers at my company still think that having the object type anywhere in the API contract is vulnerable to Insecure Deserialization. They have not yet provided a concrete demo showing a successful exploit, but they still think we need to avoid any chance of one. Therefore they want me to specify strict types in all API contracts.
In the first commit I tried making a base abstract class but .NET gives "Could not create an instance of type DeserializationDemo.BaseSetting. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."
So I then used a Custom ModelBinder in the second commit and it seems to work. However it requires casting to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. And that is the same type that DemoContract1 seems to get de-serialized to anyways when I check with a debugger. So wouldn't it be suspect to the same (hypothetical) vulnerabilities?

The only alternative I see is to avoid polymorphic types all together. To make a different endpoint, each with its own strict type, for each of the 900+ features.
My questions for the community are:

Is setting TypeNameHandling.None not enough to avoid Insecure Deserialization?
Are there any alternatives to the Custom ModelBinder that could allow me to be more strict on allowed types but wouldn't result in de-serializing to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject?


OWASP seem to think so https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Deserialization_Cheat_Sheet.html#net-csharp

For question #2, see External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?.  My answer there has several examples of cases where values declared as something more strict than object or dynamic can be subject to a type injection attack.

Beyond that, how flexible is your JSON format?  Can you share a [mcve] (not as screen shots but as text)?

Also, have you really designed 900+ data models for your 900+ features, and you just need to select the correct type based on on the "$type" property?  Do they represent some sort of type hierarchy, or do they represent aspects that can be mixed and matched?

@dbc your link talks about setting TypeNameHandling to something other than "None". My minimal example was provided above in the "this repo" link. My goal is to not need to design any data models if I can avoid them. I haven't designed any data models yet, it's the 3rd party code that has 900+ but only in docs. Type hierarchy is possible (e.g. Wifi and VPN could be child of Network) but probably not necessary. In general they are not aspects since each impacts a different feature. But perhaps some could be grouped to be aspects.

I looked a little through your minimal repro but it wasn't clear what you are trying to accomplish, which is why I'm asking for some clarification.  (And, as stated in [ask], Stack Overflow questions should be self-contained with a [mcve] and not require external repos).  If you don't want to design 900+ models why not just deserialize to say ExpandoObject?  Json.NET's ExpandoObjectConverter will deserialize to .NET built-in types rather than LINQ-to-JSON types if you don't want your Json.NET dependency to "escape" your (de)serialization code.

@dbc I don't know of any way to make the example more minimal and fit in a short code snippet. I'm sorry. As for clarification, I guess my hope is to just to
EITHER A) have some evidence that the security reviewer is correct: TypeNameHandling.None and a contract containing object type (see DemoContract1) is insecure and thus I need to do a bunch of work
OR B) enough agreement that it is sufficient to help me push back against this work.
#2 is more so helping me plan for the consequences and I should probably make it a separate question.
